# How do i write a function that detects and replaces urls in a loaded JSON?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, button

Im trying to write a function that replaces all urls in a Json with a button that leads to another function. The loaded Json with the buttons is shown on my website then.

In my component.ts the part where a Json is detected looks like that:

```
} else {
  this.downloading = false;
  this.container = <aContainer>json;
  this.loadedJson = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
```

And in the component.html the JSON gets shown on my website:

```
h3>Unrecognized JSON data:</h3>
<pre>{{loadedJson}}</pre>
```

I wanted to try it with a regExp like that to replace everything with the string: url://

```
let regExp = /url:\/\//
```

Does anybody know how i can implement code that recognizes the urls and than replaces them with a button that leads to antoher function?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pipe to transform the loadedJSON like below and [innerHTML] property binding

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: "transformURL",
  pure: false
})
export class TransformURLPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: any): any {
    if (value.length === 0) {
      return value;
    }
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      value.replace(/url:\/\//g, "<button type='button'>Test</button>")
    );
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<p [innerHTML]=" loadedJSON | transformURL"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost works! I just have the problem that just the first url gets a button and the rest stays the same. Do you know why that could be?  Also what is the "propName" property supposed to do?

Comment: filterString, propName is another optional aruguments, which is not required for this transform. You had to modify the regex to apply the button on all occurence of the url ((/url:\/\//g). Updated the answer